# Fibonacci Algorithm for big numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, fibonacci

Looking for a good algorithm to solve a Fibonacci problem
Recursive way gave me Time limit exceeded

sample input:
70007
sample out (Last digit):
3

Comment: What have you tried so far? What system gave you a timeout? What research have you done?

Comment: I would say, start with `dynamic programming` and may the force bee w/ ya

Comment: @templatetypedef int fib (int num)
{
    if (num == 1)
    return 1;
    else if (num == 0)
    return 0;
    
    else
    return fib(num-1) + fib(num - 2);
}

Comment: @Excalibur Is this for a programming competition? Is this homework? Also, can you please update your question to include that code you just described?

Comment: +1 because the question is succinct but accurate; the recursive way is pretty well-known and unambiguous. But it doesn't merit an answer though because there are plenty of google results on efficient or fast fibonacci algorithms. Here is a random decent result: http://nayuki.eigenstate.org/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Comment: @templatetypedef that's not a homework or competition its a problem on ahmed-aly online judge i just need to know the correct algorithm to solve the fibo without receiving time limit exceeded

Comment: It seems to be this problem here: http://www.ahmed-aly.com/p.jsp?ID=150

Comment: You can use the very same algorithm. Whether code is recursive or not is an implementation detail -- the very same algorithm can be implemented with or without recursion.

Comment: If asked for the last decimal digit, don't bother to compute all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a math problem and a similar problem was posted somewhat recently. A Fibonacci number can be considered to be a linear recurrence equation (recursive definition). In this case, F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2). Using an array f to represent F(n) and F(n-1), the matrix form of this is:

```
       | 1  1 |
   a = | 1  0 |

       | 1 |
f(2) = | 1 |

f(i+1) = a f(i)

f(i+j) = a^j f(i)
```

This is based on F(0) = 0, F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, F(3) = 2, F(4) = 3, F(5) = 5, F(6) = 8, ...

To speed up this process, raise the matrix a to the power j by using repeated squaring. For example, a^7 = (a * a^2 * a^4). For 32 bit n the number of loops is 32. For 64 bit n, the number of loops is 64.

However, since only the last digit is asked for, you do the math modulo 10 and with the math being done modulo 10, it turns out that a^(j%60) = a^j (this was determined using a program).

```
f(i+j) = a^(j%60) f(i)
```

so the number of loops to calculate a^(j%60) is at most 6. On my system, it takes less than 2 microseconds to calculate fib(n)%10 for any 32 bit or 64 bit unsigned integer n since the actual calculation is f(n) = ( a^((n-2)%60) f(2) ) %10 (all math operations are done %10).

This could be further sped up by simply indexing a pregenerated array of 60 characters containing the last digit of f(0) through f(59), and then indexing the array by (n%60). If the time it takes to generate the array is counted as part of the compute time, then the one time matrix calculation (6 loops max) should be faster.

The matix can be inverted and used to compute negative fibonacci values, which have the same magnitude, but with alternating sign:

```
         |  0  1  |
a^(-1) = |  1 -1  |

f(-6) = -8
f(-5) =  5
f(-4) = -3
f(-3) =  2
f(-2) = -1
f(-1) =  1
f( 0) =  0
f( 1) =  1
f( 2) =  1
f( 3) =  2
f( 4) =  3
f( 5) =  5
f( 6) =  8
```

Without the modulo 10, then the largest 32 bit unsigned value is f(47) = 2971215073, and the largest 64 bit unsigned value is  f(93) = 12200160415121876738 .

Comment: This is the right answer: a log(n) solution.

Comment: @DaveGalvin - update, I took advantage of the fact that when doing math modulo 60, a^j = a^(j%60), reducing the maximum number of loops to 6, so the solution is log2(n%60). This could be further sped up by indexing an array of 60 characters by (n%60) (not sure if this is allowed).

Comment: Look below to my answer; just realized that since we only care about the last digit, we only need to find the first few elements, because we're guaranteed a short cycle. I'm assuming we only need the last digit... not really specified by the OP.

Answer (score 2):

There's a much faster way if you only need the last digit, as in your example output. Since we're looking at the last digit, there are a limited number of possibilities before we start repeating. If we take f(1) = 1 and f(2) = 1, then note that f(61)=1 and f(62)=1 is the first repeated pair. In other words, the last digit of Fibonacci numbers is a cycle of length 60. Calculate the first 60 digits and store them in an array, then return the n mod 60 element of your array. Constant time.

Comment: Seems the current standard is f(0) = 0, f(1) = 1, so the first repeated pair, (any sequential pair of digits is all that is needed to confirm the cycle count), occurs at f(60) = 0, f(61) = 1.

Answer (score 1):

Ther are two problems here.

1. Recursion is far too slow. Couldn't be slower. Use an iterative algorithm or one of the faster ones. You can't use e.g. the Binet algorithm which gives you the answer in one step because it will yield an FP infinity for `n=70007`.
2. Integer (or long) overflow for the 70007<sup>th</sup> Fibonacci number. You need to use an iterative algorithm but only remember the last digit each time. The sum of the last digits of the last two Fibonacci numbers, modulo 10, still gives you the last digit of the next Fibonacci number.

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate the Fib number [directly](https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/10002.4-5.shtml). As I recall the exact formula can be simplified by using the floor function, but I leave it to you to investigate these issues. Summary: direct formulas are nice.

Comment: It do not works for big numbers, because the precision of decimals is too small

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * By Nedal Kouissi
 * Fibonacci
 * The Rfibonacci means that function use a recursive methode
 * the Ifibonacci means that function use an iteration methode
 */
// finction prototype
unsigned long long int Ifibonacci( unsigned int ); 
// function prototype
unsigned long long int Rfibonacci( unsigned int );

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    unsigned int f = 1000000000000;

    // display the results
    printf( "Fibonacci( %u ) = %llu\n", f, Ifibonacci( f ) );

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

unsigned long long int Ifibonacci( unsigned int x ) {
    if ( x == 0 || x == 1 )
        return x;

    unsigned int i;
    int prevP = 0;
    int prev = 1;
    int result;

    for ( i = 2; i <= x ; ++i ) {
        result = prevP + prev;
        prevP = prev;
        prev = result;
    } // end for

    return result;
} // end function Ifibonacci

unsigned long long int Rfibonacci( unsigned int x ) {
    if ( x == 0 || x == 1 )
        return x;
    else // recursive step
        return Rfibonacci( x - 1 ) + Rfibonacci( x - 2 );

} // end function Rfibonacci
```

Comment: Time limit exceeded!

Comment: That's completely aside from the fact that this gives wrong answers, due to the fact these are generic fibonacci solvers that don't have the adaptions needed to solve your specific problem.  (That's fine for an answer, as long as it says so)

Comment: @MooingDuck no its not fine! im asking for a very very big input and that's not working even on 1000

Comment: @Excalibur: You have two issues: 1) you don't know a fast fibonacci equation, and 2) you don't know how to get the last digit of a series like the fibonacci, 3) you don't know what you don't know.

Comment: @MooingDuck this forum is made to make us KNOW what we want, if some told u that u r so cool please wake up! they are lying and to get the last digit its easy num%10 and i got the result so cool down

Comment: @Excalibur: As a hint, finding the answer of fib(70001) and then doing modulo ten is not going to work.  You have to take the modulo into account _during_ the fibonacci solving step.

Comment: I just submitted an iterative version, and determined that it is possible to make an iteration version that completes within the time limit.  My total time was 3.3 seconds, and the top answers are at 0.01 seconds though, so I suspect they're using dynamic programming.

Comment: i don't know what's wrong but the function "Ifibonacci" that i developed can handle a very very big number 
i just tried 1 billion and he can solve the problem in 21 seconds
for the "time limit exceeded" it depends on your CPU, don't expect massive result. if you want fast result you need to use some formulas that gives you approximate values ! sadly not fixed values
if that's fine i'll give you the formula .